# Disable background color when specific class is being hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple html list like this...

```css
.special {
    background: yellow;
}

li:hover {
    background: purple;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Item 2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 3
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 4
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Item 5
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a menu item with the `special` class is being hovered I want the background `yellow` color to be disabled on all items except the hover.

Is there a way I can do this with `CSS` or do I need to add some `javascript`?

Comment: need to add some javascript

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) (would also have been valid for your other questions from today)

Comment: Closest you can come is using the `~` siblings combinator but it only works down the tree. So it would work on the top special only. Try it yourself `li.special:hover ~ .special{ background:none
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS. Use the selector ul:hover li to select all li tags which are descendants of uls which are being hovered on. And if you add a bit more CSS and a transition, you will get a cool effect. Try hovering over one li tag and then hovering over another one immediatly

```css
li, li a {
  transition:
    all 0.5s cubic-bezier(1,0.5,0,0.5),
    font-size 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
  -moz-transition:
    all 0.5s cubic-bezier(1,0.5,0,0.5),
    font-size 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
  -webkkit-transition:
    all 0.5s cubic-bezier(1,0.5,0,0.5),
    font-size 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
  text-align: center;
  height: 22px;
}

.special {
  background: orange;
}

ul:hover li{
  background: white
}

ul:hover li:hover {
  background: red;
  height: 35px;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul:hover li a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul:hover li:hover a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Item 2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 3
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="special">
    <a href="#">
      Item 4
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Item 5
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome, @jsmitter3 to Stackoverflow. I saw that you forgot to mark the answers as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers